# Pointers arithmetic notation

Tags: c++, pointers, iostream

I am currently trying to figure out why my program outputs weird characters. I want it to output the characters I have chosen for the array, which I have shown on the code. I don't want to use bracket notation, though. I am only using pointer arithmetic notation which is making it confusing for me.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you so much, I appreciate any help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){


char *arr = new char[10];
*arr = 'A', 'K', 'U', 'E', 'B', 'Z', 'D', 'O', 'M', 'Q';

// Show arr;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
cout << *(arr +i) << endl;
}


delete[] arr;


}
```

Comment: WHat do you think this statement does?  "*arr = 'A', 'K', 'U', 'E', 'B', 'Z', 'D', 'O', 'M', 'Q'"

Comment: Because you allocated an array of ten `char`s, you initialized the first `char` value to 'Q', failed to initialized the remaining 9 characters to anything, so that they contain random garbage, and then attempted to print 1 character q, plus 9 characters of random garbage.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The first element is set to `'A'`.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Same: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [built-in comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), `*arr = 'A', 'K', 'U', 'E', 'B', 'Z', 'D', 'O', 'M', 'Q';` will be interpreted as `(*arr = 'A'), ('K'), ('U'), ...;`; so it only assigns the 1st element of the array to `'A'`, the other elements are not initialized at all.

If you want to initialize all the elements, you could

```
char *arr = new char[10] {'A', 'K', 'U', 'E', 'B', 'Z', 'D', 'O', 'M', 'Q'};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/GCQFK43225)

Comment: Oh, thank you, thats what I wanted to know how to do

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer notation is fine. The problem is that your array isn't initialized.

`*arr = 'A', 'K', 'U', 'E', 'B', 'Z', 'D', 'O', 'M', 'Q';` first assigns `'A'` to `*arr`, then evaluates and throws away `'K'`, then evaluates and throws away `'U'`, etc. Doesn't your compiler produce a warning for this?

Elements 1 to 9 of your array are never given a value.